# Use certificate from letsencrypt with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ssl, lets-encrypt

My server uses a certificate from letsencrypt, and the https connection works great from chrome on my phone, but fails with "unable to get local issuer certificate" from my flutter app. I am using the "http.dart" library to connect. This seems to be a common occurrence and a common question, but other people seem to just turn off the cert check or include the .crt file in the project, both of which aren't optimal solutions.

Has anyone found a better solution? A different lib? A configuration that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was a faulty configuration on the server's side: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/376